# Update one database with info from another

Tags: mysql

I have this query

```
SELECT pu.payroleId, u.userId, u.firstName, u.lastName
FROM users AS u, payrole_users AS pu
WHERE pu.firstName = u.firstName
AND pu.lastName = u.lastName
LIMIT 0 , 60
```

Which selects all `userId`'s from the `users` table if the names matches the names in the `payrole_users` table (if I've got the query right!). What I need is: for each `userId`, I need to update the `payrole_users.intranetId` field. Is this possible to do with just one query or would I need to store all these as an array and then loop through the array after and then update it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
UPDATE users u, payrole_users pu
SET pu.intranetId=u.userId
WHERE pu.firstName = u.firstName AND pu.lastName = u.lastName;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try testing this query out - does it do what you want?

```
UPDATE 
    payrole_users AS pu
        JOIN
    users AS u ON pu.firstName = u.firstname AND pu.lastName = u.lastName
SET
    pu.intranetId = u.userId
```

Note that this:

`FROM tableA AS A JOIN tableB AS B ON A.id = B.id`

is effectively the same as this:

`FROM tableA AS A, tableB AS B WHERE A.id = B.id`

For more information, see [Explicit vs implicit SQL joins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44917/2359271).